# Amazon AWS SNS Delivery Status For SMS has random Log Streams

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using Amazon's php sdk.

I use Amazon SNS service to send direct sms. When I send an sms from my php application it gives me a message ID.

I have to track the delivery status of each of my message. I have enabled cloud watch logs for `Text Messaging` using `Manage text messaging preferences` settings. The IAM role is properly configured and logs end in Cloudwatch.

Now the problem I am facing is that the system creates a random log stream for every message i send.

Here is a screen shot.

[image]

I have sent six messages and all of them has been successful( I am sending them to myself). And against every message a single log stream exists.

API gives me a function to get logs based upon LogGroupName and LogGroupStream. The LogGroupName remains the same but LogGroupStream is differnt for every message.

here is the sdk call

```
$result = $client->getLogEvents([
    'endTime' => <integer>,
    'limit' => <integer>,
    'logGroupName' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'logStreamName' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'nextToken' => '<string>',
    'startFromHead' => true || false,
    'startTime' => <integer>,
]);
```

How should i get the Logs? Is there a way to tell amazon to log all of sms deliveries to a single LOG STREAM. So i know the stream and can query for logs.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know the log stream name that's created as a result of sending a particular message?

Comment: @MattS I would say there is not way to know what will be the log stream name, as the log streams are created randomly. Or atleast I think like that.

Answer (score 1):

With a Query:

```
$result = $CloudWatchclient->startQuery([
    'endTime' => strtotime("+5 minutes", strtotime($creation_date)) * 1000, 
    'limit' => 1,
    'logGroupName' => '.....DirectPublishToPhoneNumber',
    'queryString' => 'field @message like /'.$awsmessageid.'/',
    'startTime' => strtotime($creation_date)*1000,
]);

$queryid = $result->get('queryId');
sleep(2);

$result = $CloudWatchclient->getQueryResults([
    'queryId' => $queryid, // REQUIRED
]);
$result = $result->get('results');
```

The result containt the event log with sms data success

Answer (score 0):

You could use filterLogEventsMethod from CloudWatchLogsClient:

```
$result = $client->filterLogEvents(array(    
'logGroupName' => 'string', //Required
'startTime' => integer,
'endTime' => integer,
'filterPattern' => 'string',
'nextToken' => 'string',
'limit' => integer,
'interleaved' => true || false));
```

Reference: [Aws Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.CloudWatchLogs.CloudWatchLogsClient.html#_filterLogEvents)